# Multiple serial URL requests in Objective-C / iOS

Tags: objective-c, api, ios, url

I want to check the existence of various API endpoints by doing serial URL request. If the first one fails, I want to try the second one, if the second fails I want to try the third one, etc.

Here is some code I use to do this:

```
self.apiEndpoint = kApiAjaxEndpoint;
[self testEndpointWithBlock:^(id response, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        self.apiEndpoint = kApiAjaxLegacyEndpoint;
        [self testEndpointWithBlock:^(id response, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                self.apiEndpoint = kApiRestEndpoint;
            }
            [self saveApiEndpoint];
        }];
    } else {
        [self saveApiEndpoint];
    }
}];
```

So for now I'm only testing for 2 API endpoints but the moment I add a new endpoint I would need to add another call to `testEndpointWithBlock:` with error handling code.

I was wondering if you can think of a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create several instances of `NSOperation`
2. Set dependencies so that one runs after another.
3. Add to a private `NSOperationQueue`.
4. Cancel all operations in a queue if a match is found.

Comment: This seems like a nice, lightweight solution, and gets the URL requests off the main thread if testEndpointWithBlock: doesn't.

Comment: Even if you use NSOperations and dependencies, you must run asynchronous NSOperations, please see [this blog post](http://swiftgazelle.com/2016/03/asynchronous-nsoperation-why-and-how/) (it's for Swift, but you can get the idea)

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if you can think of a more elegant way of doing this?

Asynchronous problems getting quickly more complicated than one would expect. If you don't mind to utilize a third party library, you can find an easy solution to those kind of problems:

The third party library would implement a [Promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). A promise represents the *eventual* result of an asynchronous operation. Your asynchronous method for testing any endpoint may then look as shown below:

```
- (Promise*) testEndpoint:(Endpoint*)endpoint;
```

Note: no completion handler. Notifying the call-site is solved differently, through registering a success and an error handler via a `then` method (or property). The success handler passes the result back to the call-site, and the error handler passes the error back to the call-site:

```
Promise* promise = [self testEndpoint:endpoint];

promise.then(mySuccessHandler, myErrorHandler);
```

And shorter:

```
[self testEndpoint:endpoint]
.then(id^(id result){
    // result is the eventual result of the asynchronous task
    return nil; 
}, id^(NSError* error){
   // error is the failure reason of the asynchronous task
   return nil;
});
```

Note: `then(mySuccessHandler, myErrorHandler)` will return a Promise. The returned Promise's value becomes the return value of the handler (either of the success or failure handler).

So, given

```
Promise* promise = task().then(^(id result){ return @"OK"}, nil);
```

then, when the task succeeds, the below statement will eventually become true:

```
`[promise get] isEqualToString: @"OK"`
```

Otherwise, if the error handler equals `nil` as above, errors will be propagated to the child promise:

```
`[[promise get] isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]`
```

For example, using  a helper method `all:`:

#### A) Run *all* tests in *parallel* and return an array of the results:

If the test succeeds, return a string `@"OK"`, otherwise return `@"not reachable"`.

Create an array of Promises, whose associated task is already running:

```
NSArray* requests = @{
    [self testEndpoint:A].then(^id(id result){return @"OK";}, ^id(NSError* error){return @"not reachable";}),
    [self testEndpoint:B].then(^id(id result){return @"OK";}, ^id(NSError* error){return @"not reachable";}),
    [self testEndpoint:C].then(^id(id result){return @"OK";}, ^id(NSError* error){return @"not reachable";}),
    [self testEndpoint:D].then(^id(id result){return @"OK";}, ^id(NSError* error){return @"not reachable";}),
};
```

When *all* tests are finished *then* execute the handler:

```
[Promise all:requests].then(^id(id results){
    // results is a NSArray containing the result of each 
    // task above in the same order .
    ...
    return nil;
}, nil);
```

Likewise, using a helper method `any:`:

#### B) Run *all* tests in *parallel*. When the *first* finished return its result and stop the other tasks:

```
NSArray* requests = ...; // same as above

[Promise any:requests].then(^id(id result){
    // Parameter result is the result of the first task that finished.
    ...
    return nil;
}, nil);
```

When the first task finished, all other promises will be send a `cancel` message, which (if implemented) cancels the underlying asynchronous task.

Or,

#### C) Run tasks in sequence until a break condition becomes true:

```
NSArray* endpoints = ...;

const NSUInteger count = [endpoints count];
__block NSUInteger i = 0;
__block BOOL done = NO;
[RXPromise repeat:^RXPromise *{
    if (i >= count || done) {
        return nil;  // returning nil breaks the asynchronous loop
    }
    return [self testEndpoint:endpoints[i]].then(^id(id result){
        // found endpoint
        ++i;
        done = YES;
        return nil;
    }, ^id(NSError* error){
       ++i;
        return nil; // nil continues, returning an error would break the loop
    });
}];
```

For a more detailed overview of Promises and a list of implementations you may read here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184597/success-failure-blocks-vs-completion-block/219929#219929

**Disclosure:** the code snippets above used the API of the [RXPromise library](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise). Other libraries may have slightly differing APIs, and may or may not provide the same functionality. I'm the author of RXPromise.